# Running command line on multiple music files

Tags: batch-file, directory, command, flac

I am using a CLI program called metaflac (http://flac.sourceforge.net/documentation_tools_metaflac.html) to remove padding from various FLAC music files on my computer.  Using the following command in a batch file (with metaflac.exe in the same folder) successfully completes this task for an individual file:

metaflac --dont-use-padding --remove --block-type=PADDING "filename.flac"

I have to do this for several thousand files and don't want to do it all manually/individually.  Is there an easy way for me to simply direct this command to a directory and have it act upon every file in there?  This would save me a lot of time.

Thanks!

I am using Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  You can do it with a one-liner from a `cmd` prompt.

```
for /f "delims=" %I in ('dir /s /b *.flac') do metaflac --dont-use-padding --remove --block-type=PADDING "%I"
```

If you're putting this into a `.bat` script, change `%I` to `%%I` in both places.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d "C:\start\directory\*.flac"') do (
 metaflac --dont-use-padding --remove --block-type=PADDING "%%~fi"
)
```

should do this for you, scanning the entire directory tree from "C:\start\directory" for all `.flac` files and executing `metaflac` against each with your parameters.

Suggest you try a small copied subtree first, for safety's sake.

Comment: You beat me by 7 seconds.  +1 great minds think alike.  @L22: Peter Wright's code is intended for use in a `.bat` script.